# Is it possible to use the master node as slave node too in apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, distributed

i have 2 computers. one Pc and the other a laptop. i want to make a spark cluster with both of this computers. since i do not have more machines, i want to have a full use of these 2 computers. in configurations, the Pc is the master node and the laptop is the slave node.
is it possible to use the master node (the PC) as both master and slave in spark cluster? i mean by having 2 computers, is it possible to have 2 slaves and 1 master node? i want the Pc to serve as master and slave at the same time. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to use the master node (the PC) as both master and
>   slave in spark cluster? is it possible to have 2 slaves and 1 master node?

Yes it is possible, you can configure it as both.

There are so many links are available for it. You can refer it for installing. I have mentioned few links that will help you in setup.

Refer below link and update PC host Name also in Slaves files of spark conf directory and also set `SPARK_MASTER_HOST` with PC Host Name in **spark-env.sh.**

https://www.edureka.co/blog/setting-up-a-multi-node-cluster-in-hadoop-2.X/

https://dzone.com/articles/setting-up-multi-node-hadoop-cluster-just-got-easy-2